# How to execute operations in dataframe for each unique id?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
[id  purchase_date]
[1   1-1-19       ]
[1   1-4-19       ]
[2   1-3-19       ]
[3   1-5-19       ]
[1   1-10-19      ]
[...              ]
```

I want to add a column and apply a condition which will do the following:
For each id, subtract the maximum date from today's date. This will imply "inactive days". The resulting table should look like this (note, that 20 appears 3 times as user 1 appears 3 times in this table):

Today's date= January 30, 2019 (1-30-19)

```
[id  purchase_date   inactivity_days]
[1   1-1-19              20         ]  
[1   1-4-19              20         ]
[2   1-3-19              27         ]
[3   1-5-19              25         ]
[1   1-10-19             20         ]
[...                                ]
```

How would I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Make sure that purchase date is a proper datetime column:
df['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_date'])

# Define todays_date variable:
todays_date = pd.to_datetime("1-30-19")

# group by id, and transform the `purchase_date` column with an anonymous function
df['inactivity_days'] = df.groupby('id').purchase_date.transform(lambda x: (todays_date - x.max()).days)

In [7]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[7]: 
   id purchase_date  inactivity_days
0   1    2019-01-01               20
1   1    2019-01-04               20
2   2    2019-01-03               27
3   3    2019-01-05               25
4   1    2019-01-10               20
```